# Cgroup and Slurm

Tags: slurm, cgroups

I know how to use cgroups(allocating memory, cpu usage...) and slurm(submit, suspend/stop a job). I would like to know how cgroups work with slurm. Where could I fix the memory or CPU usage when I submit a job to slurm? I read the documentation from Slurm Schedmd(https://slurm.schedmd.com/cgroups.html) but it doesn't give a good explanation. Maybe it is a misunderstanding of mine. Can anyone explain how to allocate some ressource for a job using cgroup in slurm? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

`cgroup` usage in Slurm is at the admin configuration level, and is transparent for the user. When configured to use cgroups, Slurm creates cgroups for the jobs and deletes them automatically, based on the resources required at job submission (e.g. --mem, --ntasks, etc.)

Comment: What if user wants to create another cgroups level on their job's cgroups? Is it possible?

Comment: @M.Rez, no. It has to be pre-configured in cgroups.conf,